# ASP.net Core Identity User Claims different between development and production

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

I'm having an issue where the claims I create for a JWT are showing up different in production than they are on my local dev box.  Here is my code for creating the JWT and adding the claims to it:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromForm] LoginUser applicationUser)
{
    var identity = await GetClaimsIdentity(applicationUser);    //this function does the _loginManager.PasswordSignInAsync()
    if (identity == null)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation($"Invalid username ({applicationUser.UserName}) or password ({applicationUser.Password})");
        return BadRequest("Invalid credentials");
    }

    var claims = new List<Claim>
    {
        new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, applicationUser.UserName),
        new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, await _jwtOptions.JtiGenerator()),
        new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Iat,
                  ToUnixEpochDate(_jwtOptions.IssuedAt).ToString(),
                  ClaimValueTypes.Integer64)
    };

    //add role claims
    var user = _userManager.FindByNameAsync(identity.Name).Result;
    var roles = _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user).Result;

    //adding the user id to the claims so it can be used in requests
    claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Sid, user.Id));

    foreach (string role in roles)
    {
        claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role));
    }

    // Create the JWT security token and encode it.
    var jwt = new JwtSecurityToken(
        issuer: _jwtOptions.Issuer,
        audience: _jwtOptions.Audience,
        claims: claims,
        notBefore: _jwtOptions.NotBefore,
        expires: _jwtOptions.Expiration,
        signingCredentials: _jwtOptions.SigningCredentials);

    var encodedJwt = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(jwt);

    // Serialize and return the response
    var response = new
    {
        access_token = encodedJwt,
        expires_in = (int)_jwtOptions.ValidFor.TotalSeconds,
        username = applicationUser.UserName,
        roles = roles
    };

    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response, _serializerSettings);
    return new OkObjectResult(json);
}
```

When this code runs locally and I log the user's claims, the "sid" claim is always populated with the user's id (guid) which is what I need, and the "nameidentifier" claim always holds the user's username:

```
User Claim[0]: http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier Value: adminuser (96b821e8)

User Claim[1]: jti  Value: 418b19b9-e502-4391-93e4-9a66e0d68d66 (80328ff0)

User Claim[2]: iat  Value: 1486588748 (a5289382)

User Claim[3]: http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/sid    Value: c193d68b-da04-45ea-b546-8389d83076da (174611d7)

User Claim[4]: http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role Value: Admin (2cdb3902)

User Claim[5]: nbf  Value: 1486588748 (740f01f6)

User Claim[6]: exp  Value: 1486675148 (e89329cb)

User Claim[7]: iss  Value: SuperAwesomeTokenServer (63a724a0)

User Claim[8]: aud  Value: http://localhost:50824/ (f7ca0b84)
```

When this code runs in production and I log the user's claims, the "sid" claim is intermittently populated with the user's Id and sometimes not even present, while the "nameidentifier" claim always holds the user's id (guid):

```
User Claim[0]: http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier Value: c193d68b-da04-45ea-b546-8389d83076da (9393a9dc)

User Claim[1]: http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name   Value: adminuser (b9cd34dc)

User Claim[2]: AspNet.Identity.SecurityStamp    Value: 9c060086-1fa9-42f0-8ebf-2fdb3b443d53 (f9355f36)

User Claim[3]: http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role Value: Admin (4cbcb5b4)
```

Also, you can see that in prod, it's adding a "name" claim which now holds the user's username.

So 3 questions:

1. Why would the "sid" claim be missing intermittently in prod?
2. Why would the "nameidentifier" claim have a different value between Dev and Prod?
3. Why is the "name" claim only present in prod?

Other details:

Using MySql for the database.  Using IIS to serve the application locally and Kestrel to serve it in production.

Comment: Who or what is your claims provider? e.g. Identity server, Auth0, Active Directory, etc.

Comment: I'm using Asp.net Core Identity for EF Core.

Comment: I haven't used that provider but I would look to see that your production Issuer and Authority settings are correctly set for production.  It's possible those settings are still pointing at your local env.

Comment: @trevorc, that's an interesting point. I am not currently changing them between dev and prod, so they are the same.  The issuer is set to "SuperAwesomeTokenServer" and Audience to "http://localhost:50824".  Do you know what they should be set at in prod or can you point me to an explanation?

Comment: Aha! Your audience for prod env should be set to wherever your prod env is.  Common mistake I do all the time.  Also, make sure the issuer is reachable in production as well.  'SomeTokenServer' would probably not work in Azure, AWS, etc.

Comment: @trevorc, I've changed the Issuer and Audience settings but it doesn't appear to have an affect on the claims values showing up differently.

Comment: Are you using Azure AD or some other 3rd party OpenID (Goole Facebook) Provider to login with Identity?  And if yes, do you use the same application id and application secret?

Comment: @Tseng, I'm not using any 3rd party API's for authentication.  It's using asp.net core and EF core identity so all of the auth information is stored in my database in the asp.net standard identity tables.